# Bootstrap не изменяет цвет блока

Tags: css, bootstrap

Я создаю блок:

```
<div class="bg-success p-3 text-sm-center">
  This is SportsStore
</div>
```

Классы p-3 и text-sm-center работают, а bg-success не применяет цвет блока.
Версия Bootstrap:

```
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3"
```

Класс применяется к элементу, но переменная --bs-success-rgb не определена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в `:root` что есть? И подключен ли `_root.scss`?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar забыл уточнить:
Подключен только "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
В нём определена: --bs-success-rgb:25,135,84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил проблему. Дело в том, что у меня был проект Angular и я "глупо" подключил bootstrap.
Для того чтобы подружить Angular и bootstrap необходимо:
npm install bootstrap

в angular.json:

```
"options": {
  "styles": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
}
```